# Reference Request: Quadratic Optimization with affine constraints

Tags: reference-request, quadratic-programming

I was wondering what is a standard textbook/source that I can reference this fact:

> $\min_y \frac{1}{2} y^T C^{-1} y - b^T y$
>
> such that $A^T y = f,$
>
> where $C^{-1}$ is am $m \times m$ symmetric positive definite matrix, and $A$ is $m \times n$ matrix of rank $n \le m$. This quadratic constrained minimization problem has a unique solution given by the system
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} C^{-1} & A \\ A^T & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y \\ \lambda \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b \\ f\end{bmatrix}.$$

I'm currently looking at these course notes Proposition 14.3 but would like a more established reference: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis5150/cis515-12-sl14.pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis5150/cis515-12-sl14.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in Section 10.1.1 of "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe

[image]